# Using AlpineJS $persist in JavaScript instead of HTML

Tags: javascript, persist, alpine.js

Through [this article](https://codewithhugo.com/alpinejs-magic-property-access/) I learned that you can access these magic variables through JS as well (e.g. in HTML `<div x-ref="navbarCollapse">...</div>` and in JS `this.$refs.navbarCollapse`).

I was wondering whether that would work as well with the [Persist plugin](https://alpinejs.dev/plugins/persist). The goal is to store a boolean whether the user accepted the Cookie Banner.

So I tried setting the variable as if it were placed in `x-data`, which looks like:

```js
export default () => ({
    open: this.$persist(false),
});
```

but that throws:

```
module.esm.js:1656 Alpine Expression Error: Illegal invocation

Expression: "open"
```

Next I tried placing in my `init()` function (which is `async` because I use GraphQL in there)

```js
export default () => ({
    open: false,

    async init() {
        this.open = this.$persist(false);
        ...
    }
});
```

but then nothing happens.

For more context here is my currently working example with my own functions for reading/writing to local-storage.

```js
import client from './graphql';
import {
    gql,
} from '@apollo/client/core';
import {
    storageGet,
    storageHas,
    storageSet,
} from './local-storage';

const COOKIE_CONSENT_NAME = 'cookieConsentAccepted';

export default () => ({
    open: false,
    enabled: false,

    async init() {
        // Get all relevant information from the API
        const response = await client.query(
            {
                query: gql`
                    {
                        globalSets(handle: "globalsCookieBanner") {
                            ... on globalsCookieBanner_GlobalSet {
                                cookieBannerStatus
                            }
                        }
                    }
                `,
            });
        const data = response.data.globalSets[0];
        this.enabled = data.cookieBannerStatus;

        // Check whether to open cookie banner
        if (this.enabled && (!storageHas(COOKIE_CONSENT_NAME) || (storageHas(COOKIE_CONSENT_NAME) && storageGet(COOKIE_CONSENT_NAME === false)))) {
            this.open = true;
        }
    },

    toggle() {
        this.open = !this.open;
        storageSet(COOKIE_CONSENT_NAME, !this.open);
    },
});
```

Comment: Some magic variables aren't available in the functions. `$dispatch` is also not available and needs to be passed into the function. I have no experience with `$persist`, but probably if you init and pass it, then it will properly work:

`export default ($persist)`

`x-data="FUNC($persist)"`

Comment: @Yinci hmmm, yes, that seems like a nice idea. I just really hate having to place JS in HTML (this would also trigger CSP rules), that's why I try to avoid it as much as possible. But I guess there is no way around it if I really wanna use $persist. Either that or the developers at AlpineJS have to add that functionality